# Error using PyPlot in julia v1.0 in windows 10 x64

Tags: julia

I just installed julia v1.0 in windows, and add PyPlot, and then try to use.
No sucess

```
julia> using PyPlot
[ Info: Precompiling PyPlot [d330b81b-6aea-500a-939a-2ce795aea3ee]
WARNING: could not import Base.mimewritable into PyPlot
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: start not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\sysimg.jl:13
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
 [3] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [6] top-level scope at none:2
 [7] eval at .\boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [8] eval(::Expr) at .\client.jl:389
 [9] top-level scope at .\none:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\Lucas\.julia\packages\LaTeXStrings\qycAf\src\LaTeXStrings.jl:62
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile LaTeXStrings [b964fa9f-0449-5b57-a5c2-d3ea65f4040f] to C:\Users\Lucas\.julia\compiled\v1.0\LaTeXStrings\H4HGh.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:313 [inlined]
 [3] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1184
 [4] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\logging.jl:311
 [5] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:852
 [6] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:311 [inlined]
 [7] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:834
 [8] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [9] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
 [10] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [11] top-level scope at none:2
 [12] eval at .\boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [13] eval(::Expr) at .\client.jl:389
 [14] top-level scope at .\none:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\Lucas\.julia\packages\PyPlot\jXCXB\src\PyPlot.jl:295
ERROR: Failed to precompile PyPlot [d330b81b-6aea-500a-939a-2ce795aea3ee] to C:\Users\Lucas\.julia\compiled\v1.0\PyPlot\oatAj.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:313 [inlined]
 [3] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1184
 [4] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:311 [inlined]
 [5] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:941
 [6] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:852
 [7] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:311 [inlined]
 [8] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:834
```

Do i have to install Python or other external files or programs ?
Plots do not work too !

Comment: for Plots.jl try the master branch: `add Plots#master`

Comment: same for PyPlot.jl: `add PyPlot#master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Julia v1.0 is brand new, some packages are just not compatible yet. Quite often though the necessary changes have already been made but haven't been tagged (released) yet. To get the bleeding edge version of a package you can do `add Packagename#master`. In case of PyPlot, you need the master version of LaTeXStrings, a dependency of PyPlot. The following should work:

```
(v1.0) pkg> add LaTeXStrings#master
(v1.0) pkg> add PyPlot
```

Comment: hello man, can you help me ?   UndefVarError: readdlm not defined     i have this error in this version ... in older version works fine ...   i save a table in *.dat, so i have to read this table, and  the comamnd   readlm do not work

Comment: Do `using DelimitedFiles` first. `readdlm` has been moved there. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/

Comment: Hello, thanks ... just write    using DelimitedFiles  works ... now, i have another problem using PyPlot ... now my plots gives error about   linspace not defined  ... do you know how can i solve it ? in older versions, works fine my plots